# reqwest send multipart form with very large attachment

Tags: rust, reqwest

As [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65815578/4540) explains, it's possible to use `Body::wrap_stream(read_stream)` to POST the contents of a file without first reading the entire contents into memory.

How can we do the same thing as part of a `reqwest::multipart::Form`?  The following code fails with the error `` the trait `From<&mut dyn Stream<Item = std::result::Result<Vec<u8>, std::io::Error>>>` is not implemented for `Body` `` .

```
   let metadata_json = "{ \"file_owner\": \"bob smith\" }";
   let metadata_part = reqwest::multipart::Part::text(metadata_json);

   let read_stream : Stream<Item = std::io::Result<Vec<u8>> = my_file_stream;
   let stream_part = reqwest::multipart::Part::stream(read_stream);

   let multipart_form = reqwest::multipart::Form::new()
     .part("metadata", metadata_part)
     .part("file", stream_part);
```

I tried supplying an implementation of `From` that just calls `Body::wrap_stream` but it's forbidden since neither `From` nor `Body` is defined in my own code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you need to use [`Body::wrap_stream`](https://docs.rs/reqwest/0.11.2/reqwest/struct.Body.html#method.wrap_stream) like this:

```rust
let stream_part = reqwest::multipart::Part::stream(Body::wrap_stream(read_stream));
```

Comment: The stream is returning data from a C api that retrieves one buffer at a time.  Is there a more idiomatic way to represent its data?

Comment: Ah, sorry. No, then it is completely fine. (You could also flatten the `Vec`s, I suppose, but if there's no particular reason to do that, then it's completely fine as it is.) I've edited my answer accordingly.