# Return type errors making a POST request using reqwest in Rust

Tags: rust, reqwest

I'm new to Rust and Typed languages and am having trouble making a post request using reqwest in Rust. I'm not sure which arguments I should pass in to the Result return type enum.

I'm also not sure if my approach so far is the right on because I get errors when I call `.await;` after `send`. Does this function need to be async?

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
   --> rust/src/lib.rs:41:13
    |
41  |             Ok(res) => res,
    |             ^^^^^^^ expected opaque type, found enum `std::result::Result`
    | 
   ::: home/.cargo/registry/src/reqwest-0.11.3/src/async_impl/request.rs:416:26
    |
416 |     pub fn send(self) -> impl Future<Output = Result<Response, crate::Error>> {
    |                          ---------------------------------------------------- the expected opaque type
    |
    = note: expected opaque type `impl std::future::Future`
                      found enum `std::result::Result<_, _>`

error[E0308]: mismatched types
   --> rust/src/lib.rs:42:13
    |
42  |             Err(err) => err,
    |             ^^^^^^^^ expected opaque type, found enum `std::result::Result`
    | 
   ::: /home/.cargo/registry/src/reqwest-0.11.3/src/async_impl/request.rs:416:26
    |
416 |     pub fn send(self) -> impl Future<Output = Result<Response, crate::Error>> {
    |                          ---------------------------------------------------- the expected opaque type
    |
    = note: expected opaque type `impl std::future::Future`
                      found enum `std::result::Result<_, _>`

error: aborting due to 2 previous errors
```

Ultimately, I'm not sure if I'm on the right track with making a POST request using reqwest, but this is what I have:

```
enum Result<T, E> {
        Ok(T),
        Err(E),
    }

    pub async fn make_request(path: &str) ->  Result<(), ()>{

        let client = reqwest::Client::new();
        let request = client.post(format!("http://localhost:8000/{}", path))
            .body("tbd")
            .send();

        match request {
            Ok(res) => res,
            Err(err) => err,
        }
    }
```

Any advice on moving forward would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to POST a file using reqwest?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65814450/how-to-post-a-file-using-reqwest)

Comment: The problem with this code was that I made a custom enum called "Result" that wasn't implemented when I was supposed to be using the built in Result return type. When I removed the `Result` enum, the code worked. I also added `.await?` after `.send()` and replaced the match statement with Ok(())